# What's the noun for "synchronous"?

Tags: nouns

If the noun for "synchronized" is "synchronicity", what's the noun for "synchronous"? Is there even such a noun?

Comment: *synchrony* is the word you want.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I can upvote your comment, but it would be better if you posted it as an aswer which I could accept :)

Comment: Are you looking for *synchroneity*?

Comment: It's fun to see how we struggle to turn some words into different parts of speech in English. So far, suggestions include: **synchrony, synchroneity, synchronism, synchronousness, and synchronicity**. I would love to see someone draft up an answer explaining the etymology of these approaches :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noun *[synchronism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synchronism?show=0&t=1384212119)* describes events or states that are *[synchronous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synchronous)*.

Some dictionaries list *synchronism* and *[synchrony](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synchrony)* as synonyms, while some do not.

My Merriam-Webster Unabridged does **not** list *synchronousness* as a word.

Answer (score 1):

According to Merriam Webster, the noun would be [Synchronousness](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synchronous).
In that link, go down past definition 5 and you'll see **syn·chro·nous·ness** *noun*

Comment: Not a wrong answer, but I like _synchrony_ better. FWIW, OneLook finds _synchronousness_ in just [five](http://www.onelook.com/?w=synchronousness&ls=a) dictionaries, but _synchrony_ in [more than 20](http://www.onelook.com/?w=synchrony&ls=a).

Comment: Synchronousness means existing simultaneously. Synchrony means doing actions simultaneously. The user is asking for the noun that says that something exists simultaneously and therefore, synchronousness is the answer in this case.

Comment: According to NOAD, _synchronous_ means "existing or occurring at the same time," so, by that definition, and your differentiation, I'm not sure what the O.P. is asking for. Moreover, Collins defines _synchrony_ as "the state of being synchronous," which seems like it would fit the O.P.'s request. In any case, you bring up an interesting way to dissect the issue; you may want to incorporate some of that into your answer.

Comment: simultaneous action, development, or occurrence.
That's Google's definition of Synchrony.
a state in which things happen, move, or exist at the same time
As defined by Merriam-Webster.
Synchronous(ness):
a state in which things happen, move, or exist at the same time
As defined by Merriam-Webster
Hmm. I concede.

Comment: I concede because you were right. Synchrony is the best answer because it's shorter, easier to say, and has the exact same definition as Synchronousness.